# Depth camera intrinsics and recording resolution - do they need to match?

Tags: python, computer-vision, point-clouds, realsense, camera-intrinsics

I have a 455 Intel RealSense depth camera I'm trying to get up and running. I was able to find the camera intrinsics using the pyrealsense2 library like so:

```
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
cfg = pipeline.start()
profile = cfg.get_stream(rs.stream.depth)
intr = profile.as_video_stream_profle().get_intrinsics()
```

The intrinsics gives me a width and height of (848, 480). I would like to record depth data at the maximum resolution of the camera (1280,800). Will I still be able to recover point cloud data from the depth data, even if it is not recorded at the width and height I found from the intrinsics? Thanks.

Comment: can you get any other "profiles"? you're only getting the intrinsics for that profile.